# Make iterator that can be used to initialize vector

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm having some trouble creating an iterator type for my class which can be used to initialize a vector. Probably best explained with some code, here's an example of what my implementation looks like:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdint>

struct Foo
{
public:
    Foo(uint8_t i) : i(i) {}
    struct iterator
    {
    public:
        using value_type = std::pair<int, bool>;
        using reference = value_type;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        bool operator == (const iterator& other) { return cur == other.cur; }
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) { return !(*this == other); }

        iterator& operator ++ () { if (cur > -1) --cur; return *this; }
        iterator operator ++ (int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }

        reference operator * () { return std::make_pair<int, bool>(8 - cur, foo->i & (1 << cur)); }
        pointer operator -> () { static value_type v; v = *(*this); return &v; }
    private:
        friend Foo;
        iterator(const Foo* foo, int start) : foo(foo), cur(start) {}
        const Foo* foo;
        int cur;
    };

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(this, 7); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(this, -1); }

    uint8_t i;
};
```

The logic of what the class is doing doesn't matter; it's the fact that although I can use this iterator in a for loop, I get an error when attempting to construct a vector from it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// struct Foo...

int main()
{
    Foo foo(73);

    // Works, output as expected
    for (auto elem : foo)
        std::cout << "Position " << elem.first << " is a " << elem.second << '\n';

    // Works, output as expected
    for (auto it = foo.begin(), end = foo.end(); it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << "Position " << it->first << " is a " << it->second << '\n';

    // Error: cannot convert argument 1 from 'PowersOf2::iterator' to 'const unsigned __int64'
    std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> v(foo.begin(), foo.end());
}
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) tells me that `std::vector`'s constructor takes two iterators *if InputIt satisfies InputIterator*. [It also tells me](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) that the requirements for an InputIterator are

1. Satisfies *Iterator*
2. Satisfies *EqualityComparable*
3. `i != j`, `*i`, `i->m`, `++i`, `(void)i++` and `*i++` are valid

so I'm not sure what's gone wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you please explain why you're using `static` in: `pointer operator -> () { static value_type v; v = *(*this); return &v; }`? It looks very suspicious

Comment: Just to make the code example shorter, it goes via a proxy class in my actual code; the error is the same in both versions.

Comment: The answer aside. Why are your `operator ==` and `operator !=` implemented so differently??

Comment: The linked page also says `i->m` should be equivalent to `(*i).m`. This requirement isn't upheld here, since `operator->` returns a pointer to a static and `operator*` returns some unrelated pair.

Comment: @JHBonarius `operator!=` is implemented *in terms of* `operator==`, which is a normal approach to take. If you need to make a change, for example to fix a bug, you just have to make changes to `operator==`.

Comment: It seems the static `v` in `operator->` is always assigned to `operator*` before being returned. This might appear to work with what you've done so far, but something like `it->first = 5;` won't. The problem with the current iterator is that represents a `std::pair` that doesn't actually exist. It seems to me like it's `value_type` should be `std::pair<const int, const bool>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, does this mean they have to be the same object in memory? As they will both return an object which will return true if compared

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And yes, sorry there should be a lot more `const` floating about than there is. The objects you get upon referencing the iterator should be read only.

Comment: @DominicPrice I'm not sure if it's formally a requirement and I don't think that's the cause of your problem here. But what I'm sure about is that other developers and users will expect `operator->` to return a pointer to `operator*`.

Comment: You forgot to provide `difference_type` so you don't satisfy the [Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) requirement. When in doubt, `using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;` is a pretty safe bet.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Wellll now don't I feel a fool :P. That works. Will accept that as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cccpreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) the `std::vector` constructor that takes iterators *"[...] only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies InputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2)."*.

To satisfy [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) a type must satisfy [Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator). In turn, `Iterator` requires the type to provide several type alias, including `difference_type` which you've omitted.

Try adding the public type alias `using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;` to your iterator type.